# HTML Form / PHP

Tags: php, html

I am making a website and have coded a form for users to fill out and then the form should be emailed to john.doe@gmail.com. But when I upload the files on to the server, and test the form with correct details, it does not work. The html code is as follows:

```
    <form class="form" name="htmlform" method="post" action="send2.php">
    <table width="540px">
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="name">Name *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="70" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top"">
      <label for="phone">Cell Phone *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="phone" maxlength="30" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="email">Email *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

And then there is an external php file named "send2.php" which contains:

```
    $email_to = "john.doe@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Feedback Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $cell_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($cell_exp,$phone)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


// creating email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Could somebody please examine this code and tell me where do I go wrong. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,
WS

Comment: Remove the `@` from the `mail` call and try again.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't fix the issue.but it should let you know if there are any errors.Make sure to enable error reporting on your script."Doesn't work" isn't a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more specific what error are you getting ?

Also you could try using !empty () or

```
if(!isset() && !empty ()) {}
```

instead of isset

Comment: The form says it is completed when I test it and shows the success message but does send the form to my mail.

ps: i am using a free web host to upload the files...

Comment: could you please remove the @ from beginning of the mail function, @ suppress the errors, than try to execute it, it might show some error,...could be a problem with smtp settings